# Unable to parse DateTime from a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, c#-4.0

```
string dt = "10/25/2010 11:40:05 PM";
var currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; //ru-RU
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dt); //Exception!
```

How to parse that `dt`?

**UPDATE:**
In my case DateTime can be represent as  `"25.10.2010 11:40:05"` or `"10/25/2010 11:40:05 PM"`
Is these any "generic" method to parse it without changing CurrentCulture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) Date and Time format string, using either `ParseExact` or [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
                       dt, 
                       "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                       out dateTime
                      );
```

The string cannot be parsed as a Russian `DateTime` representation since the Russian culture doesn't use AM/PM, hence the use of the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which is a US like culture (it represents no specific culture, but is modeled after the en-US one).

Comment: +1 for helping him find the answer himself rather than directly answering it for him.

Comment: @Reddog : you was fast too much ;)

Comment: @Oded : I believe hours is 12-h (hh) format rather than 24-h (HH) because in this case AM/PM does not make any sense. Also `yy` is a two last year digits like `11` for 2011

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ParseExact` instead:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("10/25/2010 11:40:05 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I believe you forgot about seconds part

Comment: What's culture myDate belong to? InvariantCulture?

Comment: I was using `en-US`, but `InvariantCulture` will be more flexible.

Comment: How to get the culture of myDate?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how to retrieve the culture info after parsing the date?

Comment: You don't - you have to know it in advance. I.e. 10/01/2011 may mean January 10 OR October 1, there is absolutely no way to know that by looking at the date time value alone.

Comment: `InvariantCulture` is independent of any culture.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTime.Parse(dt, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-us"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, 
                                 "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To avoid runtime exceptions use safe [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method, it returns false in case of unsuccessfull parsing rather than throwing the [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx) exception

Answer (score 1):

Russia doesn't use AM and PM as their AM/PM designators, which is at least *one* reason that would fail. Another is that Russia may not use the "month/day/year" format which is mostly a peculiarity of the US as far as I'm aware. (I can't remember Russia's format strings offhand; I do remember that the genitive month names caused me grief recently, but that's another story...)

I would personally *explicitly* specify the culture as the invariant culture, and also explicitly specify the format string:

```
string text = "10/25/2010 11:40:05 PM";
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(text, pattern,
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If this might *reasonably* be expected to fail, you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) instead, to handle failure gracefully without involving exceptions.

Comment: +1 because your answer wasn't getting any love (and it's the right answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dt, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```