# Parsing a specific string to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

I am getting date and time returned from an API as a string in the following format:

Mon Aug 13 15:04:51 -0400 2012

Does anyone have experience with how I can turn this into a DateTime?

Comment: You could split the string for whitespaces and then use the constructor of DateTime to create your date.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854529/unable-to-parse-datetime-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Aug 13 15:04:51 -0400 2012",
                                  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You should read about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: You have missed the timezone portion. You can use `K` for this: `"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy"`

Comment: @Oded: In my TimeZone ("India Standard Time", +5h:30m), this conversion is giving me 14/08/2012 00:34:51. Why is that so?

Comment: The time difference is `5:30 + 4 = 9:30`, so 9 and a half hours of difference. That's exactly the amount of time added to get your result. Make sense? In other words, `15:04` in central Brazil is the same point in time as `00:34` in India (not taking DST into account).

Comment: @Oded: Yup. But one more ques. How to make sure that i also get `13/08/2012 15:04:51`

Comment: You need to use the same culture - instead of the defaul or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when formatting, try `pt-Br`.

Comment: @Oded: I tried `DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Aug 13 15:04:51 -0400 2012",
"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy", new CultureInfo("pt-Br")).`. It returned error.

Comment: Are you trying to parse it or display it? You need to use `ToString` to display it, using that culture. It will not parse because `Mon` and/or `Aug` are probably not valid shortcuts for Day/Month names in Portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method.

Or if you are not sure that the parsing will succeed, use the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method.

For unconventional date and time strings use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two links, I think they will be very useful to you:

[string-format-datetime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)