# string was not recognized as valid datetime in crystal report parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

```
rdoc.SetParameterValue("fromdate", Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_From.Text));
```

> dtp_From.text=12/16/2013. 
>   rdoc is reportdocument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to parse DateTime from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854529/unable-to-parse-datetime-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this date with exact date format:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtp_From.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// care, there may be another date format: "M/d/yyyy"

rdoc.SetParameterValue("fromdate", date );
```